# Why is variance formula x^2f(x), not x^2f(x^2)

Tags: probability, statistics, variance

The variance formula is $E[X^2]-E[X]^2$ and in the continuous case this means $\int x^2f(x)dx-\mu^2$. This means that $E[X^2]=\int x^2f(x)dx$ which is confusing to me because $E[X]=\int xf(x)$, so I would expect $E[X^2]$ to be $\int x^2f(x^2)$. What am I missing here?

Comment: Fixed the typo, although it's not particularly relevant to the question.

Comment: For any function $g(X)$ you have $E[g(X)] =\int g(x)\,f(x)\, dx$ when this is a meaningful integral. To find $E[X]$ use $g(X)=X$, while to find $E[X^2]$  use $g(X)=X^2$

Comment: Take the discrete example where $P(Y=1)=\frac12$ and $P(Y=2)=\frac12$.  Then $E[Y]=\frac121+\frac122=1.5$ and $E[Y^2]=\frac121^2+\frac122^2=2.5$ not $\frac1{2^2}1^2+\frac1{2^2}2^2=1.25$.  The continuous case is similar

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_unconscious_statistician.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)$ is the so-called PDF (Probability Density Function). However the variable ($X$) changes, the probability density won't change (otherwise you will get another distribution).

Edit: By the way, as the comment points out, the variance formula is $E[X^2]-(E[X])^2$, not the way you wrote it.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as to how the density doesn't change with x. To me it seems like if I was looking at, say, the normal distribution, and I looked at equal sized bands (as in for some epsilon around an input point x, integrate the function) then whether x=-2 or x=0, I will have quite different densities.

Answer (score 1):

To compute the expected value of $X^2$, using the definition of expected value rather than the LOTUS rule, what you would need to do is first find a PDF $g$ for the random variable $X^2$. Then, by the definition of expected value, we would have $E(X^2) = \int x g(x) \, dx$. Now the question is, what is $g$? That is not obvious!

The LOTUS rule saves us from the necessity of finding $g$. According to the LOTUS rule (that is, the "law of the unconscious statistician"), we have
$$
E(X^2) = \int x^2 f(x) \, dx
$$
where $f$ is a PDF for $X$.

Answer (score 0):

When we look at expected values we multiply each outcome times the probability of that outcome and sum or integrate over all possibilities.  We can use the frequency distribution $f(x)$ to find the likelihood of all possible values of $x^2$

Lets look at a simple example:

$f(x) = \begin{cases} \frac 12 & x = 0\\\frac 13 & x = 1\\\frac 16 & x = 2\end{cases}$

That is $X = 0$ with probability $\frac 12, 1$ with probability $\frac {1}{3}, 2$ with probability $\frac 16.$

What is the probability $X^2 = 4$?  It is the same as the probability $X = 2$

$E[X^2] = \frac 12 (0^2) + \frac 13 (1^2) + \frac {1}{6}(2^2)$

This example is with discrete probabilities.  As we move from discrete probabilities to continuous probabilities summation is replaced with integration.